# Can i put more than one image on paperclip model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Can i put more than one image on paperclip model? and how should i put it ?

rails g migration add_image_to_model_name

```
    def self.down
        remove_attachment :model_name, :image, :image2
      end
```

```
  def self.up
    remove_attachment :model_name, :image, :image2
  end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to create new table for paperclip attachments and setup `has-many` association between this table and your parent/existing table.

With this approach, you can upload images as many you need.

```
# app/models/gallery.rb
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Create `picture` model and migration file, then define paperclip's `has_attached_file` in `picture` model.

```
# app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  has_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"
end
```

Here is a tutorial you can refer to: [Adding multiple images to a Rails model with paperclip](http://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/)